# jsp:how to hide folder structure of website from users?

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, structure

how to hide folder structure of website from users.
 i have developed a website on jave platform (jsp).
website is deployed on jboss.
suppose my website 's home page url is

```
dummy.com/dummyFolder/dummy1.jsp
```

user can watch all of jsp pages in website by going on url

```
dummy.com/dummyFolder/
```

what should i do to prevent user to view my website directory structure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the default `web.xml` of the application server you need to disable the directory listing feature. In case of JBoss AS (specifically: Tomcat) you need to set the [`DefaultServlet`](http://www.jboss.org/file-access/default/members/jbossweb/freezone/docs/latest/default-servlet.html)'s initialization parameter `listings` to `false`:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Comment: Then you did something wrong. Ensure that you're working on the right server. Review the steps you did. Don't forget to reboot the server after the change.

Comment: is it possible to hide static resources like *.html,*.jsp

Comment: You mean hiding from *direct* access? That's an entirely different problem/story. Placing them in `/WEB-INF` and using a page controller servlet should do.